# My Java EE Project using JPA, EJP, JSF error, and need advice of best practice

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I have Java EE Application (using JPA and JSF), when I try to update the department of employee I see the entitymanager tries to change the department entity not the foreign key only,  and need to know the best practice:

JPA:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Department department;

    /* seter/getter */
    ....................
}


@Entity
@Table
public class Department implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    /* seter/getter */
    ....................

}
```

POJO:

```
      import java.io.Serializable;
      public class KeyValue<K, V> implements Serializable {

        private K key;
        private V value;

        public KeyValue() {
        }

        public KeyValue(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

      /* setter/getter */
      .................................

}
```

EJB:

```
@Singleton(mappedName="EmployeeDAO")
  @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
  public class EmployeeDAO {

  private UserTransaction transaction;

  @PersistenceUnit(unitName="databaseUnit")
  protected EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  @Resource
  SessionContext sessionContext;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init(){
      entityManager=entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
      this.transaction=sessionContext.getUserTransaction();
  }

  public void insertNewEmployee(Employee employee{
    entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        entityManager.joinTransaction();
        entityManager.persist(employee);
        entityManager.flush();
        transaction.commit();
        entityManager.refresh(employee);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}


 public void updateEmployee(Employee employee){
     try{
        transaction.begin();
        entityManager.joinTransaction();
        entityManager.merge(employee);
        entityManager.flush();
        transaction.commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public Employee findEmployee(long employeeId){
    Employee employee = null;
    try{
        employee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, employeeId);
    }catch(NoResultException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return employee;
}


  @Singleton(mappedName="DepartmentDAO")
  @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
  public class DepartmentDAO {

  private UserTransaction transaction;

  @PersistenceUnit(unitName="databaseUnit")
  protected EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  @Resource
  SessionContext sessionContext;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init(){
      entityManager=entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
      this.transaction=sessionContext.getUserTransaction();
  }


  public Department findDepartment(long departmentId){
        Department department = null;
        try{
            department = entityManager.find(Department.class, departmentId);
        }catch(NoResultException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return department;
    }

  public KeyValue<String, Long> findAllDepartmentsAsLabelValue(){
        List<KeyValue<String, Long>> keyValueList=new ArrayList<LeyValue<String,Long>>;
        try{
            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);
            Root<Department> root=criteriaQuery.from(Department.class);

            criteriaQuery.multiselect(rootT.get("name"),rootT.get("id"));
            criteriaQuery.distinct(true);

            Object[] result= entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
            keyValueList.add(new KeyValue<String, Long>(result[0].toString() , Long.parseLong(result[1].toString()));
        }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return keyValueList;
}
```

JSF:

```
 <h:form>
      <h:outputText value="employee"/>
      <h:inputText value="#{employeeBB.employeeName}"/>
      <br />
      <h:selectOneMenu required="true" value="#{employeeBB.departmentId}">
           <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="select"/>
           <f:selectItems value="#{employeeBB.allDepartments}" />
      </h:selectOneMenu>
      <br />
      <h:commandButton value="submit" actionListener="#{employeeBB.doAddNew()}" />
      <br />
      <br />

      <p:dataTable id="tblAllEmployee" rows="10" widgetVar="tblAllEmployee" editable="true" lazy="true" value="#{employeeBB.lazyData}" var="employee">
            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{employeeBB.doUpdate}" update="@this" immediate="true" oncomplete="tblAllEmployee()"/>

            <p:column headerText="Name" >
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{emplyee.name}" />
                    </f:facet>  
                    <f:facet name="input">  
                        <p:inputText value="#{employee.name}"/>
                    </f:facet>  
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="department">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{property.department.name}" />  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <f:facet name="input">  
                         <h:selectOneMenu required="true" value="#{employee.department.id}">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="select" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{employeeBB.allDepartments}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>  
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

   </h:form>
```

Backend-Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="employeeBB")
 @ViewScoped
 public class EmployeeBackend implements Serializable{

 @EJB(....)
 EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

 @EJB(....)
 DepartmentDAO departmentDAO;

 private List<KeyValue<String, Long>> allDepartments;


 private long departmentId;
 private String name;

@PostConstruct
private void init(){
 allCategories = departmentDAO().findAllDepartmentsAsLabelValue(myDatabaseCriteria));
}


/* setter/getter */
     ..................................

    public void doAddNew(){
        Department department=new Department();
        department.setId(departmentId);

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setName(employeeName);
        employee.setDepartment(department);

        employeeDAO.insertNewEmployee(employee);
    }


    public void doUpdate(RowEditEvent event) {
        Employee employee=(Employee)event.getObject();
        employeeDAO.updateEmployee(employee);
    }  

    ...............................
}
```

The Error is :

```
The attribute [id] of class [Department] is mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which call causes the error, but looking at your doAddNew method I believe I the problem.

You need to fetch the existing department from db not create new one and assign to it id as the ids are managed by EM (and that department is already in DB).
So your code should start:

```
Department department = departmentDAO.find(departmentID) //where find calls EM.find method
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setDepartment(department);
```

Comment: Thanks on your answer :), I got the error when i try to update the employee.

Comment: add cascade={CascadeType.MERGE} on your ManyToOne annotation it should solve the problem.